# Getting the connection property has not been set error

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

As said in the title, I tried to write some prepared statement on Visual Studio 2017. 
But when Starting my program, I have an exception, called

> System.InvalidOperationException :'The connection property has not
>   been set.'

Here's the associated code :

```
namespace Sequence
{
   class Database
   {
    private MySqlCommand cmd;
    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn;    //new connection

    public void Connect()
    {
        string myConnectionString;  //connection String

        myConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;" +
    "pwd=;database=internship;";

        try
        {
            conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
        }
        catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }


    public void Disconnect()
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public void AddData()
    {
        cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand();
        //Connecting to database
        Connect();
        try
        {
            //Prepare a statement
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO storing VALUES(@longitude, @latitude, @status, @path)";
            cmd.Prepare();
            //Adding values
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@longitude", 0.5);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@latitude", 0.5);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", "false");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@path", "C:\\temp\\sequence");
            //Executes the Query
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //Writes in Console
            Console.WriteLine("Line added successfully");
        }
        catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex.Number + " has occured: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }



        }

    }
}
```

This is my class that connects to the database.
I have a main program where I just wrote this :

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Database db = new Database();
        db.Connect();
        db.AddData();
        db.Disconnect();
    }
}
```

Any idea of why I get this exception ?

I followed the tutorial on this link : 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-prepared-preparing.html

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't set the connection property of your command:

```
cmd.Connection = conn;
```

Although it's recommended to use the [`using-statement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) that *Provides a convenient syntax that ensures the correct use of `IDisposable` objects* like `SqlConnection`. It will also close the connection

Comment: Thanks ! 
I forgot this line yeah, thanks a lot !

I have an error now, but it's something easier to fix : I have an auto increment column, and I don't know what to write in my prepared statement thing to make it work.
I'll check this on the web.